# LabVIEW Eror Code 1671 (Related to Python Script), How can I handle it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, labview

I am trying to call a python function to LabVIEW using some nodes. However, I am getting an error (code:1671) related to python. Could you please help me to solve this error? Thank you. I am using LabVIEW 2023 Q3 and Python 3.6.0 both 64 bit.

1. Here is the error mesage from LabVIEW:

> Python Node in labviewdeneme.vi<APPEND>
> Module Path: "C:\Users\GörkEmir\Desktop\pythoncode\deneme3.py"
> Function Name: getClassData
> Python returned the following error: <class 'UnicodeDecodeError'>
> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 11: invalid start byte

2. Here is the Python code:

```
#define class
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self, parameter):
        self.__Parameter = parameter
    def GetValue(self):
        return self.__Parameter

#define wrapper for LabVIEW Python node        
def getClassData():
    newClassObject = myClass(4882)
    value = newClassObject.GetValue() 
    castedValue = int(value)
    return castedValue
```

I tried to change python code such as casting or converting string to int and int to string. But they did not work.

Comment: Please show how you're calling this. I don't see how this could cause an error related to character decoding.

Comment: Hi, here is the LabVIEW vi:      https://hizliresim.com/p9bpvim

Comment: Modify your `def getClassData()` to simply return an integer, like `return 5`. Does it work now? If not, it's probably caused by wrong return type selection. If it works, can you figure you which row exactly causes the error?

Comment: Hi, I solved it. I tried it as you suggested (returning a basic integer), but it did not work. Then, I realized that in Module Path, there was "ö" letter, as you can see at the error message. I changed the path such as C:\pythonFile.py, it worked. The "ö" latter causes this error. English is not my first language, I should not use foreign characters for paths such as "ö", "ğ", "ü"...